# Angular: A way to discern a service caller

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Background:**

A complex Angular feature module with nested components and services. The top-level components are subscribed to a subject to be notified and notify up about an error caught inside the module.

**The problem:**

**ALL** top-level components receive error notifications (as they are subscribed to subject.next messages) and react

**The solution implemented:**

Filter via the 'fingerprint', but this requires all methods in all services, that are wired with a .catch() to be added a 'fingerprint' parameter.

For example:

```
...
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

    getSth (idOfWhatToGet: string, fingerprint: string) { // <<< !!! fignerprint
         this.http.get('myurl') 
            .toPromise()
            .then(a => a)
            .catch(err => this.subject.next({err, fingerprint}); // <<< !!!
}
```

Top level components:

```
...
@Component({...}) 
export class SomeTopLevelComponent {

      @Output() onError = new EventEmitter<Error>();
      private myFingerprint = 'STL_component';
      ...
      this.subject.subscribe(errMsg => errMsg.fingerprint === 'myFingerprint ' ?
          this.onError = errMsg.err);           // <<< !!! fingerprint filtered
}
```

> Is there a way to discern which component called a service ?

And if no, what could be an optimal workaround or better than putting 'fingerprint' parameter to each service call ?

**More details**

Let's assume there's an Angular project which uses a feature UI module, consisting of:

- 2 top-level components
- 10 reusable components inside
- 5 shared-by-all services, each service with 3 methods (all methods
  return Promise)

The feature-module-exposed-elements (top-level-components) are used usual:

```
<my-angular-project> 
    <feature-el-1 (onError)="callErrHandler($event)></feature-el-1>
    <feature-el-2 (onError)="callErrHandler($event)></feature-el-2>
<my-angular-project>
```

Both feature-el-1 and feature-el-2 components are subscribed to incoming error messages:

```
OnInit() {
   this.subjectSubscription = this.errorService.getErrorsMessages()
      .subscribe(errorMessage => this.onError.emit(errorMessage.err));
}
```

And all services dispatch error, when such is caught:

```
...
doSth.then(p => ...)
    .catch(err => this.errorService.sendErrorMessage({err})
```

And the error service is implemented similar to:

```
@Injectable()
export class errorService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    sendErrorMessage(message: {err: Error}) {
        this.subject.next(message);
    }

    getErrorsMessages(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Now, `<feature-el-1>` and `<feature-el-2>` load their data by calling a method on same service, let's say `getAddresses()`. What happens next: the call initiated from `<feature-el-1>` succeeds and the call from `<feature-el-2>` fails. But **BOTH** `<feature-el-1>` and `<feature-el-2>` will receive the error and will raise `onError` event up (and we want only one of them, namely - the one whose service crashed, to raise the event).

To fix this, we use 'fingerprint' - a parameter added to each service method call based on some logic (indicating downstream which top level component the error occured) so that the exposed top-level component can decide - to raise or not the received error message. It's bulky and cumbersome logic code body, so all is down to the main question - **can a service know (as when it knows it can pass this knowledge back, figuratively speaking) which component called him?**

Comment: I don't completely understand. Who calls `getSth()` and how does that caller know what the `fingerprint` value should be. Is it only called by `SomeTopLevelComponent` because it has `myFingerprint` as private. If it's the only component with that `fingerprint` value then why not just handle the `catch` inside that component instead of the service? Can you explain more?

Comment: @ cgTag, I added a "More Details" section, hope it clarifies

Comment: I can solve this by changing how the service is injected into the component so that it's not a singleton. Would that work for you?

Comment: That is interesting. If I get your idea right, you mean to have an instance per "hierarchy", figuratively speaking - ok break the singleton idea of the service, but achieve the 'fingerprint' - to know who's the caller ? A concern may be support-wise - in a large project. But still wonder if Angular is meant to have some getCaller functionality

Answer (score 0):

You have a service named `SharedService` that handles Http requests for a back-end API, and you want to listen for *errors* at a top-level component. You want to share the service so that other components can use it, but you don't want to share errors.

You've run into the problem of when the service emits an error you don't know which top-level component was responsible for the original Http request.

```
<my-angular-project> 
    <feature-el-1 (onError)="callErrHandler($event)></feature-el-1>
    <feature-el-2 (onError)="callErrHandler($event)></feature-el-2>
<my-angular-project>
```

In the above example; you have two feature components named `feature-el-1` and `feature-el-2`. Each component needs to emit only errors that originated from that component or one of it's children.

### Use Component Providers

Remove the `SharedService` from your `NgModule` providers array, and add it to the providers array of each feature component.

```
@Component({
      selector: 'feature-el-1',
      providers: [SharedService],
      template: '<child-feature></child-feature>'
})
export class FeatureElOneComponent {
      @Output() onError: Observable<Error>;
      constructor(service: SharedService) {
           this.onError = service.errors;
      }
}

@Component({
      selector: 'feature-el-2',
      providers: [SharedService],
      template: '<child-feature></child-feature>'
})
export class FeatureElTwoComponent {
      @Output() onError: Observable<Error>;
      constructor(service: SharedService) {
           this.onError = service.errors;
      }
}
```

Now that you have `providers: [SharedService]` defined for each component, then each component receives a **new** instance of that service. They will not share the same service.

Now, let's look at the `<child-feature>` component.

```
@Component({
      selector: 'child-feature',
      template: '<span>Child Feature</span>'
})
export class ChildFeatureComponent {
      constructor(service: SharedService) {
           service.doSth().then((data)=>console.log(data));
      }
}
```

This component is used by **both** feature modules, but each instance of `ChildFeatureComponent` receives a different instance of `SharedService`. So when the child component used inside `FeatureElOneComponent` triggers an error only that feature component receives the errors.